# Message box appears twice C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want a message box to appear to let the user know when they uncheck a checkbox they will lose the values in two related textboxes. The problem is when the user clicks 'cancel' the message box appears again. In the event a user does click cancel I want the checkbox to remained checked.

```
if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
{
    checkBox2.Checked = false; checkBox3.Checked = false;
    checkBox4.Checked = false; checkBox5.Checked = false;
    checkBox6.Checked = false; checkBox7.Checked = false;
    checkBox8.Checked = false;//Disable preceeding checkboxes
    enableAllAssessmentsToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
}

if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
{
    //Check if checkbox has been checked 
    textBox1.Enabled = true; textBox2.Enabled = true;//Enable that Line's Textboxes
}
else
{
    //Or not
    textBox1.Enabled = false; textBox2.Enabled = false;//Disable that Line's Textboxes
}

if(textBox1.Text.Length != 0 || textBox2.Text.Length != 0)
{
    //If associated textboxes contain text
    DialogResult  Result1 = MessageBox.Show("The numbers you have input on this row will be lost", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (Result1 == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
    }
    else if (Result1 == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the outer scope above your `if`

Comment: There is just allot of code to control the other elements of the form, but i can do

Comment: In which event is this code?

Comment: The event is when the checkbox changes, private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Are you calling this from the check changed event? (and wondering why the event handler fires againwhen you change the check value)?

Comment: the method is private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Tip: `== true` is usually redundant. Just use `if (checkBox1.Checked)`. `x == false` is also typically better written `!x`. (If you ever come across a situation where it’s not redundant, you have bad code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have this code in `CheckedChanged` handler of `checkBox1`. If current state of `checkBox1` is not checked, then you are changing it's state when user cancels message box, and you are executing this handler again.

If handler is subscribed you cannot avoid it's executing when state of checkbox is changed. But you can unsubscribe handler:

```
checkBox1.CheckedChanged -= checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
checkBox1.Checked = true;
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
```

Or use some boolean flag to indicate this case:

```
void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (shouldNotHandle)
        return;

    // ...

    else if (Result1 == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        shouldNotHandle = true;
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
        shouldNotHandle = false;
    }
}
```

Or (maybe better solution) you should re-consider your logic.

---

I think better solution will be setting `AutoCheck` of this checkbox to `false` and subscribing to `Click` event instead of `CheckedChanged`. That will allow you manually change state of checkbox according to conditions:

```
private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox1.Checked = !checkBox1.Checked;

    if (textBox1.Text.Length != 0 || textBox2.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        if (UserConfirmedWarning("Numbers will be lost"))
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = true;
        }
    }

    if (!checkBox1.Checked)
        DisablePreceedingCheckboxes();

    SetLineTextboxesEnabled(checkBox1.Checked);
}
```

I also extracted some code to other methods:

```
private void DisablePreceedingCheckboxes()
{
    checkBox2.Checked = false; 
    checkBox3.Checked = false;
    // ...
}

private void SetLineTextboxesEnabled(bool enabled)
{
    textBox1.Enabled = enabled;
    textBox2.Enabled = enabled;
}

private bool UserConfirmedWarning(string message)
{
    return MessageBox.Show(message, "Warning",
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Comment: Ok so should i have the if statement in another method, perhaps one that is called when the value changes

Comment: Ahh.. I like this idea

Comment: @MichaelHancock I added another solution with little refactoring of your code which I find more appropriate than using flag or removing/adding handler

Answer (score 2):

This is happaning because you're setting Checked property to true when user clicks Canclec in the messagebox. This fires the CheckedChanged event again.

If you need this checkbox to be checked, simply use a "flag" and set it to true after Cancel is pressed to block the event to be fired.

Something like this:

```
if (flag) return;

if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
{
checkBox2.Checked = false; checkBox3.Checked = false;
checkBox4.Checked = false; checkBox5.Checked = false;
checkBox6.Checked = false; checkBox7.Checked = false;
checkBox8.Checked = false;//Disable preceeding checkboxes
enableAllAssessmentsToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
}

if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
{
//Check if checkbox has been checked 
textBox1.Enabled = true; textBox2.Enabled = true;//Enable that Line's Textboxes
}
else
{
    //Or not
    textBox1.Enabled = false; textBox2.Enabled = false;//Disable that Line's Textboxes
}

if(textBox1.Text.Length != 0 || textBox2.Text.Length != 0)
{
//If associated textboxes contain text
DialogResult  Result1 = MessageBox.Show("The numbers you have input on this row will be lost", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
if (Result1 == DialogResult.OK)
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox2.Text = "";
}
else if (Result1 == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    flag = true;
    checkBox1.Checked = true;
    flag = false;
}
```

}

Comment: If i don't the checkbox becomes unchecked which is something i don't want to happen, how else can i keep the box checked

Answer (score 2):

Since you are calling from within the CheckChanged event handler, and if this is really what your logic imposes, then I'd use a boolean variable as a flag to avoid calling the code twice.

```
    bool setFromHandler = false;
    ...
    setFromHandler  = true;
    checkBox1.Checked = true;
    ...
    if(setFromHandler)
    {
    ...
    }
    else
    {
    ...
    }
```

Cheers